# c++: Test if code is in a catch block

Tags: c++, exception, boost

I am trying to make a generic exception framework based on boost::exception.
For that, I use macro like this one:

```
#define AR_THROW_EXCEPTION(internalMessage)\
BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(boost::enable_current_exception(ArException())\
<< internal_message(internalMessage)\
<< inner_exception(boost::current_exception()))
```

My problem is that "boost::current_exception()" will terminate my program if it is not called from a catch block.
To avoid to define a second macro "AR_RETHROW_EXCEPTION", I would like to be able to do

```
#define AR_THROW_EXCEPTION(internalMessage)\
BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(boost::enable_current_exception(ArException())\
<< internal_message(internalMessage)\
if (IS_IN_CATCH_BLOCK)\
<< inner_exception(boost::current_exception()))
```

Do anybody know a way ?

Comment: Why don't you just add a parameter to your own throw statement where the user provides an enumeration to say that they're rethrowing (which would indicate being in a catch block).  You can default it to NOT_IN_CATCH so you don't have to provide it normally.

Comment: Must you use Boost.Exception? Can you use C++11's std::current_exception() instead?

Comment: w00te: for now, I have two mcro, which is the same as one with a parameter.

Comment: KennyTM: i am working on android and ios, i'm not sure if they support c++11 :>